# Angular + Nestjs Deployment

Tags: angular, heroku, deployment, nestjs

I'am trying to develop a project with nestjs and angular. My project folder like this,

Project folder

|--server (Nestjs app)

---|client (Angular app)

---|---front

i can run this app in localhost just fine. But i'am trying to deploy to heroku. I build angular app and copied these files to folder called front. And then i'll drag this folder in server folder.

In app.module.ts file in nestjs app :

```
@Module({
 imports: [UserModule,


TaskModule,
  MongooseModule.forRoot(secret.mongoUrl),
  LoginModule,
  SignUpModule,
  ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
    rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'front')
  })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

Now when i've started my nestjsapp wiht npm start my angular and nestjs app perfectly worked on localhost:3000.

Here is my heroku **build log**,

```
    -----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.18.3...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.6
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       
       > bcrypt@5.0.0 install /tmp/build_742df812/node_modules/bcrypt
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
       
       [bcrypt] Success: "/tmp/build_742df812/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" is installed via remote
       
       > @nestjs/core@7.3.2 postinstall /tmp/build_742df812/node_modules/@nestjs/core
       > opencollective || exit 0
       
       
       > server@0.0.1 postinstall /tmp/build_742df812
       > nest build
       
       client/e2e/src/app.po.ts:1:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'protractor' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       1 import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/add-task/add-task.component.ts:2:39 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       2 import { FormControl,FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/add-task/add-task.component.ts:3:35 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       3 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/app-routing.module.ts:7:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       7 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/app-routing.module.ts:8:51 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       8 import { Routes, RouterModule, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/app.component.ts:1:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       1 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/app.module.ts:2:47 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common/http' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       2 import { HttpClient, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/app.module.ts:3:30 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       3 import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/app.module.ts:4:31 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       4 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/app.module.ts:5:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       5 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/app.module.ts:6:33 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common/http' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       6 import {HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/app.module.ts:13:49 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       13 import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/guards/auth.guard.ts:2:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       2 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/guards/auth.guard.ts:3:83 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       3 import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
                                                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/home-page/home-page.component.ts:4:35 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       4 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/login/login.component.ts:2:35 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       2 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/login/login.component.ts:3:39 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       3 import { FormGroup,FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/nav-bar/nav-bar.component.ts:1:35 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       1 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/services/auth.service.ts:2:34 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@auth0/angular-jwt' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       2 import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/services/auth.service.ts:3:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       3 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/services/auth.service.ts:4:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common/http' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       4 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/services/auth.service.ts:5:24 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       5 import { Router } from '@angular/router';
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/services/task.service.ts:3:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common/http' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       3 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/services/task.service.ts:4:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       4 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/services/token.interceptor.ts:2:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       2 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/services/token.interceptor.ts:8:8 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common/http' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       8 } from '@angular/common/http';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/services/user.service.ts:4:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common/http' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       4 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/services/user.service.ts:5:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       5 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/show-task/show-task.component.ts:2:35 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       2 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/show-task/show-task.component.ts:3:30 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       3 import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/sign-up/sign-up.component.ts:2:40 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       2 import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/sign-up/sign-up.component.ts:3:35 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       3 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/app/task/task.component.ts:5:35 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       5 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/main.ts:1:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       1 import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/main.ts:2:40 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       2 import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/test.ts:4:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core/testing' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       4 import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       client/src/test.ts:8:8 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       8 } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       node_modules/ngx-spinner/lib/ngx-spinner.component.d.ts:1:79 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       1 import { OnDestroy, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChange, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
                                                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       node_modules/ngx-spinner/lib/safe-html.pipe.d.ts:1:40 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       1 import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';
                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       node_modules/ngx-spinner/lib/safe-html.pipe.d.ts:2:31 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
       
       2 import { PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       
       Found 40 error(s).
       
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 1
       npm ERR! server@0.0.1 postinstall: `nest build`
       npm ERR! Exit status 1
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the server@0.0.1 postinstall script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.euxxt/_logs/2020-08-25T12_12_21_031Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       - A module may be missing from 'dependencies' in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#ensure-you-aren-t-relying-on-untracked-dependencies
       
       Love,
       Heroku
        !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
        !     Push failed
```

nestjs package.json

```
 {
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/src/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "postinstall": "nest build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^7.0.2",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/serve-static": "^2.1.3",
    "bcrpyt": "^2.0.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.25",
    "ngx-spinner": "^10.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^7.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.3",
    "@types/jest": "25.2.3",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.7.32",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "3.0.2",
    "eslint": "7.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "jest": "26.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "26.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

angular package.json

```
 {
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "(if exist ..\\server\\front rmdir ..\\server\\front /s /q) && ng build --prod && move dist/client ..\\server\front",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.6",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.1",
    "auth0": "^2.27.1",
    "enhanced": "^1.2.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^10.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

Right now i'am so confused and i don't know what to do. Any help would be great thanks for your time

Comment: Can you add your `package.json`? It looks like a) it's trying to build some test files, so stopping that would be a good idea, and b) it's not finding your `@angular/` modules

Comment: I added package.json files.  I think it can't find angular modules too. But how can i solve that  ?

Comment: Oh, you have two separate `package.json`s in your repository? That could be where an issue is coming in with Heroku. [This repository](https://github.com/jmcdo29/zeldaPlay/tree/deployment) (and the `deployment branch` specifically) has a setup with `server` and `client` under the same `src` and using the same `package.json`. It's a home rolled monorepo, but if you plan to keep using a monorepo, [`Nx`](https://nx.dev) might be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer btw! I looked at this repo.  But really i don't get it :/  https://github.com/Puv0/todoapp this is my repo If i'dont bother you can you give me some advice what should i do ?

Comment: Part of the issue is that you have a `package.json` in your root directory that does not contain all of the dependencies for your project. Another issue is that your `tsconfig.build.json` is trying to build everything. Your `src`, your `client`, all of it. Let me know what you don't get. Generally, this directory structure isn't really great or clear how you'd run it all through a few build processes

Comment: Well i'm newbie in web development and nestjs/angular because of that i really don't know how can i merge 2 package.json files or how fixing tsconfig.build.json issue etc.
What would be the best project folder approach for deploy to heroku ?

Comment: You an either follow the custom monorepo approach I have in the `deployment` branch of the repo above, use a monorepo management tool like `nx`, or come up with your own solution. In general, there should be one pacakge.json in your project. Your `tsconfig` needs to specify what should be built and what should be ignored, and all of your src code (read: ts files) should be under the same directory instead of across several root directories.

Comment: Thanks for advice! i updated my repo.I splited server and client folder. Angular app worked in nestjs app so i just deployed my server folder to heroku and done! https://todoappxyz.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

nest build is a wrapper on top of the standard tsc.
It does not add any other compilation features or steps except for handling tsconfig-paths out of the box.

by runing `nest build`  u will compile:

|--server (Nestjs app)

& ---|client (Angular app)

I would suggest you migrate your application to nx monorepo with nest + ng
(there is also an cli that creates all the files for you, you just need to copy your application into the right folder

`npx create-nx-workspace@latest`)..

or ignore the path from -|client (Angular app) inside your tsconfig from nestjs.